# How to make `kpse.find_file` aware of `\input@path` modifications?

Tags: luatex, external-files, lua

I'm working on a `\graphicspath` like feature for GregorioTeX and having some problems making `\input@path` work with our Lua code.  Basically, while `\input@path` works for `\input` statements, before we input the file our Lua code first locates the file using `kpse.find_file` so that it can be checked to see if it is up to date (and regenerate it from the appropriate source file if not).  The problem is that `kpse.find_file` does not seem to be aware of the definition of `\input@path`.

So my question is what do I need to do to pass the definition of `\input@path` over to Lua so that `kpse.find_file` will search those additional paths for the file it's looking for?  Alternatively, is there another way of locating the file in the Lua code that is aware of `\input@path`?

Since this involves accessing multiple files, I've posted my [MWE as a zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfirzyrmz1ujdve/MWE.zip?dl=0) file with the appropriate directory structure.

Comment: The `kpse` environment variables (in your case `TEXINPUTS`, probably), are set up when `luatex` is started. I'm not sure whether the Lua `kpse` library can change the values on the fly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\input@path` is a very trivial system it just loops over the list until it finds something so if the list is aa/,bb/,cc/  and you are looking for file.foo then you want to do

```
kpse.find_file ("file.foo") or
kpse.find_file ("aaa/" .. "file.foo") or
kpse.find_file ("bbb/" .. "file.foo") or
kpse.find_file ("ccc/" .. "file.foo")
```

so all you need to do is pass in `\input@path` split it up to a Lua table then iterate through the table until you find the file

So... if the subdirectory `zzz` has a file `test.foo` we can find it using TeX or Lua via:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{aaa/}{zzz/}}
\def\maketabl#1{\ifx\relax#1\else,"#1"\expandafter\maketabl\fi}
\directlua{
input_path = {""\expandafter\maketabl\input@path\relax}
}

\begin{document}

\IfFileExists{test.foo}{\typeout{FILE is \@filef@und\space (TeX)}}

\directlua{
f="test.foo"
%
for i,k in pairs(input_path) do
fp=kpse.find_file(k .. f)
if (fp) then
print("FILE is " .. fp .. " (Lua)")
break
end
end
}

\end{document}
```

which makes the terminal output

```
FILE is zzz/test.foo  (TeX)
FILE is ./zzz/test.foo (Lua)
```

Comment: the number of z are back to normal ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer one day I'll buy you a UK keyboard, then you too will be able to find `z`.

Comment: but I wouldn't dare to use them, they are yours ;-)